# Can you be "in comradery" as you are "in friendship"?

Tags: word-usage

Because you can be in friendship with your friend, is it valid to say that you are in comradery with your comrade?

Comment: Have you checked a good dictionary for the meaning of *comradery*? You seem to mean *comradeship* rather. They do not mean the same thing, or at least the usage is not the same.

Comment: `comradeship` that's what got me confused!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comradeship is the term you are looking for, note the two related and [much less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comradeship%2Ccomradery%2Ccameraderie&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomradeship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomradery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccameraderie%3B%2Cc0) terms  camaraderie and comradery.

[Comradeship](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comradeship):
​

> the feeling of friendship between people who live or work together, especially in a difficult situation. (Cambridge Dictionary)

and

> ***Camaraderie*** is the warm feelings of friendship, closeness and loyalty shared among a group of people or a team of people. Camaraderie is a relatively new English word, added in 1840. It comes from the French word, camaraderie, meaning a convivial feeling among comrades.
>
> ***Comradery*** means the warm feelings of friendship, closeness and loyalty shared among a group or people or a team of people. Comradery is a nativization of camaraderie. It appears in 1879, derived from comrade+ery. Comradery is a North American iteration of the word camaraderie, notice that the spelling as well as the pronunciation drops a syllable from the middle of the word camaraderie.

(The Grammarist)